# How to dismiss modal navigation page using Prism NavigationService?

Tags: prism

In my root view model I call something like

```
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(
    "/NavigationPage/Page1of2",
    useModalNavigation: true
);
```

Sure enough it loads both view models in a modal navigation just fine. In `Page1of2ViewModel` I do another

```
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(
    "Page2of2",
    useModalNavigation: false
);
```

Which view model now should dismiss that modal and how?

Using `GoBackAsync()` or `GoBackAsync(useModalNavigation: true)` neither of the 3 view model seem to be able to dismiss the *modal flow* back to my root view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you place a "/" in you are signifying an absolute navigation. This is resetting the navigation stack completely.  It's the same as MainPage = new MyPage().  So there is no modal navigation occurring here.  The only way to pop a page off the stack is to use the NavigationService.GoBackAsync, or use the built-in software/hardware buttons to go back.

Comment: Typical copy-paste error. I totally didn't look at that `/`. Everything works as expected now... I feel so stupid.